# Can't disable newsstand notification per-day limit in iOS8

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ios8, newsstand-kit

I tested my newsstand app on two iOS8 devices (8.0.2 and 8.1) and get background notification only once in 24 hour period.

Does anyone know how to disable this limit in iOS8?

I'm not 100% sure that the problem is in OS version, but **in iOS7 everything works fine**.

---

### This is what I did:

According to the [Apple FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2280/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011215-CH1-DELIVERING_YOUR_CONTENT-THE_CONTENT_OF_MY_PUBLICATION_NEEDS_TO_BE_UPDATED_THROUGHOUT_THE_DAY___CAN_I_INITIATE_A_NEWSSTAND_BACKGROUND_DOWNLOAD_MORE_THAN_ONCE_IN_A_24_HOUR_PERIOD_):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"NKDontThrottleNewsstandContentNotifications"];
```

iOS8 Registration code:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = 0;
    types |= UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
    types |= UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
    types |= UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

My payload:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1}, "issue_id":"issue01"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the note in that FAQ?

"Note: A development device refers to a device which has been recognized in Xcode Organizer as having the "Use for Development" checkbox enabled."

However that may have changed in iOS8(But I see no mention of that in the fact), my app don't need newsstand currently...

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.1. It seems that there is no "Use for Development" checkbox in the "Devices" window anymore.

Comment: Another iOS developer just told me this doesn't work anymore since iOS 8. I guess Apple changed their mind but didn't told anyone :(